# Replace <space>[ using sed

Tags: linux, shell, replace, sed, substitution

I am getting a weird error while replacing `[` with `|`. Please note there is a space before `[`. Closing bracket doesn't have the same issue.

```
# sed -i 's/ ]/|/g' test.txt -->Working
# sed -i 's/ [/|/g' test.txt --> Not Working
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: just escape the bracket? `sed -i 's/ \[/|/g'?`

Comment: @krork You have to use backticks in comments for code highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Sed expects you to close the square bracket, which is a special character (starts a character class – see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions), the `[list]` example). If you want to use it literally, you have to escape it:

```
sed -i 's/ \[/|/g' test.txt
```